# Change variable in parent component in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm using angular 7. And I have child component like below stackblitz. But, I can access my variable on parent control by `@Input` but I couldn't change. How can I  do this in below stackblitz? **My aim is hiding modal by set displayPopup=false on hide button click**

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epjvop?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpopup%2Fpopup.component.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is an `EventEmitter` on the `popup.component.ts`

Here is a working example:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup.component.css']
})
export class PopupComponent {

  @Output() public hide: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

  hideModal() {
      this.hide.emit();
  }
}
```

then on the parent you can subscribe to that event like this:

```
<app-popup *ngIf="displayPopup" (hide)="displayPopup = false;"></app-popup>
```

Comment: @realist use `EventEmitter<void>()` to resolve this issue.

Comment: EventEmitter<void>() solve that warning. Thanks @trichetriche  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kn5tkm It can be seen from this worked stackblitz

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom two-way binding like [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8grdf?file=src/app/popup/popup.component.ts) :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup.component.css']
})
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {

  private _bool: boolean;
  @Output() boolChange = new EventEmitter();

  set bool(value) { this._bool = value; this.boolChange.emit(value); }
  @Input() get bool() { return this.bool; }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  hideModal() {
  this.bool = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked perfectly @trichetriche I thougt it can be more easily but it's very complex.

Comment: Which is more common way? JamieRees 's answer or yours? @trichetriche . Because that solution very short.

Comment: Most common would be @JamieRees. Mine is more complex (but would allow you -with some more code- to get rid of the *ngIf). As a beginner, choose his solution over mine !

Comment: Thanks a lot again @trichetriche.